# Data Date 8/31/18, Excel Graphing 8/1/18

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a data set that uses the end of month date, i.e.,  7/31/18, 8/31/18; however when I graph the data the axis is showing 7/1/18, 8/1/18, etc.  I have tried correcting it in the Format Axis pane, but to no avail.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange issue

The following worked for me:

Format Axis -> Axis Options -> Axis Type -> Text Axis

Comment: That worked!  Thank you so much!